# Can we hide Photos/Videos on iPhone 6s and higher?

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, privacy

I want to hide photos and videos on my iPhone 6s. Can I do that directly or I need any apps for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accepted answer is correct, but it's worth noting that hidden photos are still fully visible in the "Hidden" album (they're merely hidden from the other views, as Phong said).

To truly hide a photo so that no one other than you can see it, use the following alternate method:

1. Create a new note
2. Add the photo to the note
3. Delete the original photo from the Photos app (it will still remain visible in the note)

   - Also delete the photo from the "Recently Deleted" album, otherwise it will remain there for up to 40 days
4. Lock the note

Now, there's no trace of the photo in the Photos app at all, and your fingerprint (or password) is required to unlock the note to view the photo.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with iOS 8, you can hide a photo or video from the **Photos** app by opening it, then tapping the **Share Sheet** (box with upward arrow). On the bottom row of share actions, tap *Hide*.

You can select multiple photos and hide them in a single stroke this way.

This will hide the photo or video from **Moments**, **Collections** and **Years**, but not from **Albums**. Starting with iOS 11, hidden photos will no longer appear in automatic albums such as **Bursts** and **Selfies**.